# mysqldump via SSH to local computer

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ssh

I have an SSH access to production server of the Rails app.

I want to make a mysqldump of production database to my Mac. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Assuming that the MySQL Database is not available from outside, you can setup an ssh tunnel `ssh -v -L 13306:production_mysql_server:3306 -N production_server` and then use `mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -P 13306...`

Comment: in Lars' command, `-v` is for verbose, and if your database server is on the same server as the app, you can use `localhost` for the value of `production_mysql_server`. `-N` is for "no command", because you're just specifying the tunnel.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Direct method to dump mysql data from remote server to your local computer is:

```
ssh root@ipaddress "mysqldump -u dbuser -p dbname | gzip -9" > dblocal.sql.gz
```

Or

```
ssh -l root ipaddress "mysqldump -u dbuser -p dbname | gzip -9" > dblocal.sql.gz
```

Both command does the same work.

If you have password for ssh and database access there will two prompt for password or if you have no password for ssh then you will be asked to enter you database password.

Similarly, if you are using key from aws or cloud other service you can incorporate the key in the command as:

```
ssh -i key.pem root@ipaddress "mysqldump -u dbuser -p dbname | gzip -9" > dblocal.sql.gz
```

Comment: Do these solutions still need enough free space on server to perform the dump and gzip? I need to do it on a server without enough space for the dump file. thanks

Comment: you can also apply compression as a flag (`-C`) in ssh (only advised on slow connections!). the `-9` in gzip specifies a number to (from the manual): _Regulate the speed of compressio [...] `-1` or `--fast` indicates the fastest compression method (less compression) and `--best` or `-9` indicates the slowest compression method (optimal compression). The default compression level is -6 (that is, biased towards high compression at expense of speed)._

Comment: re:memory - mysqldump and gzip use memory (buffering, caching) and _can_ use it sensibly (blocks, pagination). you'd want to make sure that when trying to use as little memory as possible, the resulting delays/extra CPU usage don't introduce inconsistencies, as then your file would be useless. some more information (note the different host/client situation!) https://serverfault.com/questions/850811/memory-use-during-mysql-gzip-backups

Answer (score 4):

1. Connect to server via ssh: `ssh remote_username@remote_host`
2. Go to 'current' folder
3. Make a dump: `mysqldump -u username -ppassword -h host database > dump.sql`
4. Disconnect from server
5. Copy a dump.sql file to local computer: `scp remote_username@remote_host:/path/to/dump.sql /Users/YourName/Documents/dump.sql`
6. Connect to server via ssh again and go to 'current' folder
7. Remove dump.sql file: `rm dump.sql`

Comment: Easy solution when you have plenty of free space in the ssh server.

Comment: This isn't what the answer asks. You should remove your answer. The question is how to do so directly from server to local, not how to make it on server and then copy the dump file...

Comment: as tiomno indirectly says, this only works if you have free space on the server. in addition, you need write access on the server...

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get the other ones to work.

This is the solution I found for linux:

```
ssh username@ipadress "mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DB_NAME " > ~/dump.sql
```

This will prompt you to enter a password for your ssh server, and then dumps the database to the specified location on the SSH server.

Comment: this gives event not found response

Answer (score 1):

An **alternative** way to backup via SSH is to **create an SSH tunnel**, like this:

```
ssh -f -N -L 3307:localhost:3306 root@111.122.133.144
```

here, `-L` is used to specify the ports (in the format `port:host:hostport`) to create the tunnel;
the `-f` option backgrounds ssh; and
`-N` means *no command execution*, just forward ports

after that you can connect to the database as if it were a local server

```
mysqldump -u user -ppassword -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 --all-databases > backup.sql
```

note the port number `-P` matches the one specified earlier

Run a restore process is even easier

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -ppassword < backup.sql
```

This approach can be convenient when you don’t want to put one command into another (for example, due to confusion with the quotes).

Examples with mysql backup via SSH connection:

[Access Your Database Remotely Through an SSH Tunnel](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205408088-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel)

[Over SSH – Remote MySQL Backup](https://sqlbak.com/blog/over-ssh-remote-mysql-backup-dump-transfer/)