# How to export a database via SSH?

Tags: mysql, ssh, server, putty

I am trying to export the database of my project as a backup, however when writing the command it's nothing happened,

I am writing the code for dump/export my database

```
                 mysql>mysqldump -umyusername -p mydatabasename >mydatabasename_bckup.sql
```

and after that when enter the button, it's something like

```
                  mysql>mysqldump -umyusername -p mydatabasename >mydatabasename_bckup.sql

                  >
```

And it's nothing happening.

Comment: putty can do port forwarding. Use this to connect a local port to the remote database port/socket. Then `mysqldump --host 127.0.0.1 --port X ....`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024280/mysqldump-via-ssh-to-local-computer

Comment: @danblack, appreciate for your help here, however, i am trying to do same command line that you have suggested, the thing is that the NEXT line is ">" and after it's nothing happeing, however can you write the full command thanks

Comment: mysqldump isn't a mysql prompt command. Its a executable on its own, so the mysqldump command is run in the shell/window/terminal.

Comment: exit mysql and run that command from outside. mysqldump is a shell command.

Comment: thanks all now using the same that you mentioned , however error is "-bash: f:dbcerca_bckup.sql: Permission denied".

Comment: @Shaahiin, i did but i mentioned error above

Comment: you seem to be running mysqldump on the remote linux machine using a local windows path. This won't work. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52774791/10195153).

Comment: Thanks @danblack yeah, you are right , so, is it not possible through command to export the database.

Comment: put the mysqldump command after the plink command in the previous link, execute that locally. redirect the output of the plink file to a local file. Good luck. Have a good weekend.

Comment: @danblack, Thanks and same to you, I hope will done.

Comment: @danblack, i tried with same and it's working however it's not saving my 80 MB of sql file in  to system. thanks

Comment: Hey all, I have done, it, first i was need to make a folder in server then export file and it has done command tmp$ mysqldump -uce -p ce > ce_backup.sql......thanks for all support, happy weekend to all